# Windows 10 increasing in sluggishness

Tags: windows, performance

For months my WIndows 10 laptop has been getting more and more sluggish, as measured in e.g. video rendering speed in Youtube, zooming in GOogle Maps etc. I initially suspected the sluggishness was just happening in Chrome due to the various addons, but after starting Chrome in safe mode, some sluggishness remains (e.g. speed of scripts running in Matlab etc) so this is probably a more general WIndows problem.

I should add this is not a hardware performance issue, as the laptop is quite new (i7@7500, 8GB RAM) and had been super fast until only relatively recently. I don't remember having installed any particularly demanding software or addons.

Nor is it an Internet connection issue, since for instance any content streamed through a browser I don't use (Edge), and/or with Windows started in safe mode, runs smoothly.

What I already tried:

- monitoring the Task Manager for executables/apps using up inordinate amounts of CPU or mem - nothing seems suspicious
- System Restore (unfortunately this had been accidentally turned off, thus cannot use)
- complete anti-virus check with updated definitions
- restarting Windows in safe mode helps (PC runs smooth), however I have many installed programs and it'd be tedious to work down which components that auto-load are responsible for this sluggishness

I know these symptoms can describe many many underlying problems, but I'm hoping to get at the bottom of it. Short of reinstalling WIndows, is there anything else I can try?

Comment: Use Autoruns (Microsoft SysInternals) to get a good handle on what is starting. You wrote "I have many installed programs " .  It may be worth your whild to do a Windows 10 Repair Install and Keep Everything.   https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button, select Run.
This will launch the Repair and proceed normally.

Comment: Thanks John I will try this.

Comment: All the issues you mention concern the Internet, not your laptop *per se*. Try tools to measure the actual performance of the laptop, e.g. https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001467.htm , and your Internet speed separately, e.g. SpeedOf.Me .Also note that since *many* people are at home, browsing the web, sites are overloaded and are slower.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that the Internet is not actually at fault, since for instance any content streamed through a browser I don't use (Edge) runs smoothly. Added this into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing a repair installation on Windows that didn't help, what did help was to install the beta version of Chrome (as no newer stable version was available), which probably refreshed some corrupted files that were making the PC sluggish not just within Chrome but also outside it, whenever Chrome was running.